# Xslt to xsl-fo transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I want make a xslt transformation to xsl-fo but I´m not really sure that I can do this. I try to convert a XML list to a xsl-fo list. Can anyone tell me where can i look for I´m googling for a long time are there aren´t a lot of examples of this. My XML is like this.

```
 <p>TEXT</p>
 <ul>
   <li>Item1</li>
   <li>Item2</li>
 </ul>
 <p>ANOTHERTEXT</p>
```

I try use templates for this transformation but my templates don't work to get xsl-fo Can anybody tell me if the templates work in this transformation. If they work can show me an example i can't find anyone. My objetive is get a pdf whit fop

Thanks

---

This is part of my XML document I recived some parts of the source in HTML and I change HTML to XML now I try convert XML (whit a list) into XSL-FO whit a XSLT. My problem is that I can´t aply templates to this transformation. My final objetive is get a pdf whit FOP.

Thanks

UPDATE

This is my XML:

```
<Memoria>
  <name>TITLE</name>
  <Index>INDEX 2010</Index>
  <Seccion>
     <name>INFORMATION</name>
     <Contenido>
       <p>TEXT</p>
       <ul>
     <li>ITEM1</li>
     <li>ITEM2</li>
      </ul>
      <p>ANOTHER</p>
    </Contenido>
  </Seccion>
</Memoria>
```

I'm testing your solution Thanks all

Comment: HTML does not have a 100% translation to XSL-FO.

Comment: What is the exact desired result? Please, edit the question and provide. XSLT experts rarely are also xsl-fo - cognizant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're having issues with your templates not working, it might be a namespace issue. You should update the question with a more accurate example of your XML.

Here's an example.

**XML Input** (fixed to be well-formed)

```
<root>
  <p>TEXT</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
  </ul>
  <p>ANOTHERTEXT</p>  
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <fo:root>
      <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page" page-width="8.5in" page-height="11in">
          <fo:region-body margin="1in" margin-top="1.5in" margin-bottom="1.5in"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
      </fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </fo:flow>
      </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p">
    <fo:block>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ul">
    <fo:list-block padding="4pt">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:list-block>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="li">
    <fo:list-item>
      <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
        <fo:block>&#x02022;</fo:block>
      </fo:list-item-label>
      <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
        <fo:block>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </fo:block>
      </fo:list-item-body>
    </fo:list-item>    
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSL-FO output**

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
   <fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page" page-width="8.5in" page-height="11in">
         <fo:region-body margin="1in" margin-top="1.5in" margin-bottom="1.5in"/>
      </fo:simple-page-master>
   </fo:layout-master-set>
   <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
      <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
         <fo:block>TEXT</fo:block>
         <fo:list-block padding="4pt">
            <fo:list-item>
               <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
                  <fo:block>•</fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-label>
               <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
                  <fo:block>Item1</fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-body>
            </fo:list-item>
            <fo:list-item>
               <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
                  <fo:block>•</fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-label>
               <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
                  <fo:block>Item2</fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-body>
            </fo:list-item>
         </fo:list-block>
         <fo:block>ANOTHERTEXT</fo:block>
      </fo:flow>
   </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

**Apache FOP output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have an xhtml file (no < br > etcetera). Then apply an xslt transformation to create the fo file, then feed that to fop and the pdf emerges.

Snippet of xslt fo style:

```
  <xsl:template match="html:body">
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="all-pages">
      <fo:title>
        <xsl:value-of select="/html:html/html:head/html:title"/>
      </fo:title>
      <fo:static-content flow-name="page-header">
        <fo:block  font-weight="bold" font-size="16pt" space-before.conditionality="retain" xsl:use-attribute-sets="page-header"><!--  space-before="{$page-header-margin}"  -->
          <xsl:if test="$title-print-in-header = 'true'">
            <xsl:value-of select="/html:html/html:head/html:title"/>
          </xsl:if>
        </fo:block>
      </fo:static-content>
    </fo:page-sequence>
  </xsl:template>
```

Check http://www.w3schools.com/xslfo/default.asp for xslfo syntax.

See http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk/running.html for info on running fop; download of fop.jar must be nearby.

Running from vba for example as follows:

```
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    cmd = "java -Dfop.home=" & baseDir & " -cp " & baseDir & "build\fop.jar org.apache.fop.cli.Main -fo " & foName & " -pdf " & pdfName
Call shell.Run(cmd, vbWindowFrame, True)
```

(similarly from command line)